# AngularJS : Change placeholder text for Angular-chosen plugin when there is no match

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-chosen

As you can see from title, I tried to change the placeholder text which says "No results match" and which is grey-out(disabled) from a selected tag.

I tried with "placeholder" but it doesn't work.

```
<div>
    <select chosen disable-search="true" id="newpaymentMethod"
            placeholder="Placeholder text"
            class="easytrade-input full-width" name="newpaymentMethod"
            ng-model="vm.newRecord.paymentMethod"
            ng-options="paymentMethod.type as paymentMethod.description
                for paymentMethod in vm.paymentMethodOptions"
            required>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then I tried with "no_results_text", still doesn't work

```
<div>
    <select chosen disable-search="true" id="newpaymentMethod"
            no_results_text="Placeholder test"
            class="easytrade-input full-width" name="newpaymentMethod"
            ng-model="vm.newRecord.paymentMethod"
            ng-options="paymentMethod.type as paymentMethod.description
                for paymentMethod in vm.paymentMethodOptions"
            required>
    </select>
</div>
```

Any idea about it ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After I have checked the GitHub documentation of [Angular-Chosen](https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen), I found how to use the "no_result_text".

Please see below piece of code :

```
<div>
    <select chosen disable-search="true" id="newpaymentMethod"
            no-results-text="'Placeholder test'"
            class="easytrade-input full-width" name="newpaymentMethod"
            ng-model="vm.newRecord.paymentMethod"
            ng-options="paymentMethod.type as paymentMethod.description
                for paymentMethod in vm.paymentMethodOptions"
            required>
    </select>
</div>
```

So you have to use "no-results-text" instead of "no_results_text" and also the text should be wrap in ' ' like following " 'text here' "

Hope will help someone my answer :)